# Прописать путь к css. Spring проект.

Tags: веб-программирование, html, css

[image]

body {
             margin: 0;
             }

```
#head{
      height: 150px; /* Высота блока */
      width: 100%; /* Ширина блока */
      background: red;
      opacity: 0.8;
     }     


<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../resources/css/main.css">
```

Подключаю вот так, не работает. Все те же самые стили до этого лежали в самом html - все работало. Подскажие, как прописать путь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас практически правильно, нужно только на уровень выше:

```
../../resources/css/main.css
```

Comment: Не работает:(
Хотя все логично, должно работать. 
Из стилей, когда все это было в html ссылался на изображения ./resources/image/fon.png

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/main.css"> 
вот это заработало, не понимаю, в чем логика

Comment: @alex91, всё это зависит от логики `spring`, видимо, основной `html` файл сохраняется в папку `webapp`

Comment: а из css к изображениям вот теперь только так работает:)
 background: url(../../resources/image/mainfon.png)

Comment: логика тут простая, вспомните команду Change Directory (CD или CHDIR) параметр ".." в ней означает на уровень вверх, вот и гуляйте по каталогам, хоть куда.

Answer (score 1):

".." - это выход на уровень выше.
"/" - вход в папку/файл.